# How can my client catch mapservice timeouts?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server

I've got a gp service that exports pdfs using connections to mapservices.  I'd like to write to a log file when a request to a service times out.  For WMS mapservices I see I can use [IWmsClientEvents](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IWMSClientEvents_Interface/002v000000m9000000/) outbound interface on the [WmsConnection](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/WMSConnectionClass_Class/002v000000r9000000/), but for the [AGSServerConnection](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/AGSServerConnectionClass_Class/002v00000008000000/) I don't see any outbound events.

Is there a way to find out when a draw request to an arcgis server mapservice times out?

Comment: @Krik If you are using ArcGIS Server 10.1 then using ArcGIS admin API it might possible..

Answer (score 1):

You could open a log file for GP service failure.  Detailed logging will provide the point of failure.

I have GIS data export functions in GP services --a succesful export must be within web, REST, and AGS timeouts (set in config files) in my case.  I have the benefit of timeout error messages to the application, however if the python script/GP service fails it's up to my detailed logging to figure out where the script failed i.e. which timeout.

I wanted to capture the timeout alerts from the server but was told by the DBA that ideally a log (or email alert) should come from the GP failure and it would be an extra step to figure out the script failure from the DB end.

Comment: Thanks, but my GP service is consuming mapservices.  While this works great for monitoring my gp service, what I really need is a way to determine if a particular mapservice layer in a map being printed was included.  The gp service prints using arcobjects, so I'd really like a way to test if the mapservice is available, otherwise the print will be lacking info from that layer.